# Run Tomcat and its container on different JDKs

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I'm trying to run a Java Servlet application using Tomcat.  The Tomcat 7 server needs to be run on JDK 1.7 for it to not crash or not serve completely blank pages (even though it should work on 1.6), but the servlets / JSPs need to be running on JDK 1.6 because we're using some old libraries incompatible with 1.7.

Is it possible to run the Tomcat server on a different version of the JDK / JRE than the pages in the container, in general?  If so, generic instructions on how to do this would be great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Luckily it seems they don't even read the same environment variables.  The JSPs/servlets in the container seems to run whatever JAVA_HOME points to, and Tomcat seems to run whatever JDK_HOME points to.  This is my super hacky workaround for a project set up with maven.